# Export Excel To PDF excludign hidden tabs

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

I am trying to export Excel files to PDF. I am having success with this using the Microsoft.Office.Interop namespace. I am now trying to find out how to exclude tabs that are marked hidden, so that they are not within the PDF> Hase anyone done this or knows how to do this? My code is shown below that I am currently using.

```
 string inFile = @"C:\Users\casey.pharr\Desktop\testPDF\3364850336.xls";
        string outFile = @"C:\Users\casey.pharr\Desktop\testPDF\3364850336_noHidden_out.pdf";
        string tempFile = @"C:\Users\casey.pharr\Desktop\testPDF\temp.xls";

        try
        {
            //first copy original file to temp file to work with
            File.Copy(inFile,tempFile, true);

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            app.Visible = false;
            app.DisplayAlerts = false;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wkb = app.Workbooks.Open(tempFile);

            for(int x = app.Sheets.Count-1; x-1 > 1; x--) 
            { 
                Excel._Worksheet sheet = (Excel._Worksheet)app.Sheets[x];
                //now delete hidden worksheets from work book. This is why we are using tempFile
                if (sheet.Visible == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetHidden || sheet.Visible ==  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVeryHidden && sheet != null)
                {
                    //is sheet hidden. If so remove it so not part of converted file                        
                    sheet.Delete();
                }
            }



            wkb.ExportAsFixedFormat(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, outFile);

            wkb.Close(false);
            app.Quit();

            //return outputLocation;
```

The error that occurs on calling .Delete() is below:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
enter code here
```

So we can convert the pdf's fine, but not remove or exclude hidden worksheets. I went the route to try to delete them then convert the entire file, but not working.

Comment: Your code is working with no issue on VS 2017/.NET Framework 4.6.2 and the latest version of the Office 2016. What versions of the office/framework do you have?

Comment: I am trying to delete hidden worksheets though, and only convert non hidden worksheets. I will update the code. I get an error everytime i try to delete a hidden worksheet as we only want pdf conversion for visible worksheets.

Comment: No need to delete hidden worksheets, the Export method itself is skipping them already.

Comment: No problem lol, confusion is very often the root cause of many problems.